# Redirect /forgot-password/12345 -> /forgot-password.php?reset_key=12345

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to set up `.htaccess` to allow for clean password reset URLs as follows:

The user is sent a link like:

`www.url.com/forgot-password/12345`

This should be rewritten as:

`www.url.com/forgot-password.php?reset_key=12345`

(and only for this page which is `forgot-password.php` - I want to keep the query strings for the other pages as-is.)

So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !forgot-password
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forgot-password.php?reset_key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it's not working. When I dropped the second line, it seems to trigger properly, but it's not passing the `?reset_key` `$_GET` parameter in properly.

FYI, above this in my `.htaccess`, I already have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^forgot-password/(.+)$ /forgot-password.php?reset_key=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly and much neater to do it in one line.